# resolving pointer inside PE structure

Tags: portable-executable

I am analyzing PE structure. 
some article in MSDN(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985997.aspx) says

```
"IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT" points to the imports(an array of IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR structures).
```

I checked the actual value with 010 Editor PE template.
however the value seemed to be encoded somehow and I don't know how to interpret.
pictures below clearly explains this situation problem.
some advice would be appreciated...!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked through [the template](http://www.sweetscape.com/010editor/templates/files/PETemplate.bt), and it would appear that the "FOA" comments are generated by passing an RVA to the "RVA2FOA" function, which looks like it's converting the RVA to a file offset.

That makes sense, the file offset is something you often want to know (especially in a HEX editor, where you have to navigate by file offset), and FOA looks like it can be short for File Offset Something-or-other.